# Orchard CMS and controller vs driver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am a little ashamed for asking so many questions, but I really want to learn.
In [Sipke's blog](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1) a webshop is created. There is one specific question that boggles my mind when trying to do something similar.

Let me spell out the basic requirements:

- User registration form and login, etc. This one is covered by the blog and it works nice.
- Creating product parts and so on. This one is covered and no problem there.
- Ordering by filling in an order form and making the payment. See down
- Having the order page maintainable by customer. See down.
- Viewing your own orders and their status. See down
- Maintaining customers and orders from backend system. This one is covered by the blog and I need to do some work there yet.

As for items regarding creating orders and viewing your orders. I have followed the approach for creating records and using standard MVC controllers. But then I encountered problems:

1. Menu for orders page. This I had to do manually after installing the module.
2. The order page itself. I had to create the view including title and so on. But I can imagine a customer wanting the order page on another menu and with a different title. And maybe add even some own content to the ordering page. This I couldn't achieve by using standard MVC approach. So maybe I am using the wrong approach here. So I was thinking about using contentparts for creating an order and displaying them and using the drivers and handlers for that. But before I go down that road and refactor everything I want to know if that is the right approach. A downside could be that once the module follows that route it can then not so easily be reused with customers that have other cms's capable of hosting an MVC3 module.

So when to use drivers, handlers and contentparts and when to use standard controllers and views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Drivers and Parts (with Handlers if needed) when you want to create functionality for content items. E.g. if you want to display a custom media with all products, you could create a Part (together with its Driver, etc.) to handle that. Read the [docs on Parts](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part).

If the functionality is not tied to content items the most possibly you want to use the standard MVC toolbox, it's fine. Look at the built-in modules how they do that. E.g. the Blog module uses controllers and views to show the admin UI, but has parts to enhance the functionality of for example the Blog content type.

To make things more complicated [you can employ ad-hoc content items](http://english.orchardproject.hu/blog/the-orchard-dynamic-page-pattern) to build a page that you'd normally do with simple views, but that's an advanced topic :-).

Comment: I have tried the ad-hoc content item route. The example provided there doesnt work in 1.5. I get an error on the line "public ContentPartDefinition PartDefinition { get { return TypePartDefinition.PartDefinition; } }" in the file ContentPart.cs. The object TypePartDefinition is null.

Comment: Answered there, but copying here for sake of simplicity:

I use this exact same pattern in a 1.5.1 site with no problems.

However, I've got such errors (with 1.5, with 1.4 it was fine) when dynamically welding parts in the same manner on regular content types, i.e. content types that also have a static schema (like the built-in Page). If you want to do this, it's possible, but you have to weld the parts on the content item as late as possible. For this you can use regular content events, I advice to weld parts on regular content items in the OnGetEditorShape, OnGetDisplayShape, OnUpdating.